# jquery remove class at radio button

Tags: jquery, class, radio-button

I am having trouble trying to remove a class from a grouped radio button. I have two groups of radio buttons. I want to remove the class checked from all radio buttons the same group.

My problem is the class is removed from all radio buttons or from nothing.
Here you can see

http://jsfiddle.net/Tabes/awt158ep/9/

I have tried:

```
$this.parent().siblings('label')
    .find('.panel_radio').removeClass('checked');
```

and also:

```
$this.parent().siblings('label')
    .find('input:radio[name=' + $this.attr('name') + ']').removeClass('checked');
```

but neither of them have worked

```
(function($){
$.fn.meRadioCheck = function() {
    return this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $span = $('<span/>');

        $span.addClass('panel_'+ ($this.is(':checkbox') ? 'check' : 'radio'));
        $this.is(':checked') && $span.addClass('checked'); // init
        $span.insertAfter($this);

        $this.parent('label').addClass('panel_label')
        .attr('onclick', ''); // Fix clicking label in iOS
        // hide by shifting left
        $this.css({ position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' });


        // Events
        $this.on({
            change: function() {
                $('input:radio[name=' + $this.attr('name') + ']').parent().removeClass('active');

                if ($this.is(':radio')) {
                    $this.parent().siblings('label')
                    .find('.panel_radio').removeClass('checked');
                }
                $span.toggleClass('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
                $this.parent().toggleClass('active', $this.is(':checked'));
            },
            focus: function() { $span.addClass('focus'); },
            blur: function() { $span.removeClass('focus'); }
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Don't try to get around the rule that JSFiddle needs to be accompanied by code. Please add some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the same name attribute to the span element:

```
var $this = $(this);
var $span = $('<span/>');
var name = $this.attr("name");   
$span.addClass('panel_'+ ($this.is(':checkbox') ? 'check' : 'radio'))
     .attr("name", name);
```

Then you can remove the checked class from the `.panel_radio` elements with that name attribute:

```
if ($this.is(':radio')) {                    
    $this.parent().siblings('label')
                  .find('.panel_radio[name="'+ name +'"]')
                  .removeClass('checked');
}
```

Try the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tum0oega/).

Comment: @Tabes, if this worked for you please click the check mark on the left of this answer to "accept" it.